# Curl cannot post file if size > 2 GB

Tags: bash, shell, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to post file which has size of > 2 Gb and curl command fails with out of memory error.

```
curl:option --data-urlencode: out of memory
```

Curl command I am using:

```bash
curl -X POST -k --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header accept: text/csv --data-urlencode 'form_id=' 12 \
    --data-urlencode 'list_id=' 25 --data-urlencode 'file_name@' list.csv \
    https://example.com
```

Comment: I've never tried and I know very little about `curl`, but in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793166) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222806) there are mentions to adding a `-T` option to the call. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, In the first example it's binary file and mine is csv file however, I tried to use -T to pass input filename but received error. Warning: you can only select one HTTP request method! you asked for both PUT Warning:(-T, --upload-file) and POST(-d, --data)

Comment: It seems like we can do only one method and since I am also passing couple of variables like form_id and list_id so just trying to figure it out how can we pass them when I use -T option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround suggested by @daniel-stenberg can be done by manually URL encoding csv file along with other URL parameters with python

```
printf "%s" "list_id=25&form_id=12&file_name=" > encoded.txt
python3 -c "import sys;import urllib.parse; [print(urllib.parse.quote(line)) for line in sys.stdin]" < some.csv | tr -d '\n' >> encoded.txt
```

Result: a long single line of URL encoded data
`cut -c 1-100 encoded.txt`
`list_id=25&form_id=12&file_name=date%3Bcount%3Bunique%3Btotal%0A1641168000%3B4%3B3%3B3%`

Optionally, test decode the output file

```
python3 -c "import sys;import urllib.parse; [print(urllib.parse.unquote(line)) for line in sys.stdin]" < encoded.txt | head -n 50
```

Result of decode test should correctly show file contents

```
list_id=25&form_id=12&file_name=date;count;unique;total
1641168000;4;3;3
1641772800;8;7;10
1643932800;8;5;15
1644192000;11;8;23
1644796800;13;10;33
1645401600;8;8;41
1646784000;10;9;50
```

Then used in curl as

```
curl <other options> -T encoded.txt <URL>
```

Alternative solution. The previous one is better for me as it doesn't store big strings in variables but writes directly to file and doesn't use `sed -z` which needs to read the whole file to encode new lines.

```
opts="$(python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<<"list_id=25&form_id=12&file_name=")"
enc="$( while read line ; do python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<<"$line" ; done < some.csv | sed -z 's/\n/%0A/g')"
echo "${opts}${enc}" > urlencoded.txt
```

Answer (score 12):

`--data-urlencode` will load that 2GB data into a memory buffer, then URL encode it into a new memory buffer to encode it, meaning it needs >4GB memory for this operation.

A future enhancement of curl could be to (make it detect the huge size and) switch to a streaming approach.

A work-around for you could be render a URL encoded file "manually" (with the complete contents you want to send to the server) and then use `-X POST -T file` with that.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am bit confused when you say to include complete contents to single file. Do you mean to the csv file I am passing to sever? I am passing these contents currently 'file_name@' list.csv, 'list_id=' 25, 'form_id=' 12. Do we need to provider --header and --accept etc. as is into that file?

Comment: Can someone please look into this, I've added all my content from above command to filename called as file and executed curl command as curl -x POST -k -T file https://example.com but it gave me bad request(400)

Comment: My file contents looks like this --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header accept: text/csv --data-urlencode 'form_id=' 12 --data-urlencode 'list_id=' 25 --data-urlencode 'file_name@' list.csv

Comment: Try encoding the csv with `while read line ; do python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<<"$line" ; done < some.csv > urlencoded.txt` and then use as `-T urlencoded.txt`. BTW, @daniel-stenberg is the creator of `curl` which is turning 25 years old!!!

Comment: Encoding new lines also: `python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<<"$(sed -z 's/\n/%0A/g' some.csv)" > urlencoded.txt`

Comment: @LMC Thank You!, Wow, It's good to know that Daniel Stenberg was the creator of curl. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: @LMC I've one final question though, I can run your script to encode csv file but how about passing other variables like 'list_id=' 25, 'form_id=' 12 ? Initially I used to send them using --data-urlencode but as we are using -T now this can be no longer used.

Comment: @sandy try `python -c "import urllib;print urllib.quote(raw_input())" <<<"list_id=25&form_id=12&file_name=$(sed -z 's/\n/%0A/g' some.csv)"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252727/discussion-between-sandy-and-lmc).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that what is receiving the data on the other side is a standards-compliant HTTP server you can stream this over as a multipart request with the following command:

```bash
curl -k --header 'Accept: text/csv' \
  -F 'form_id=12' -F 'list_id=25' \
  -F 'file_name=<list.csv' \
  https://example.com
```

Which will come across like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
Accept: text/csv
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------0989cede5f5f71c0

--------------------------0989cede5f5f71c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_id"

12
--------------------------0989cede5f5f71c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="list_id"

15
--------------------------0989cede5f5f71c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"

1,2,3,4...
```

and shouldn't run afoul of your memory limits.

There are a lot more options you can specify for the `-F`/`--form` option as well, including various encoding options. See the man page.

Comment: Thank You!! This worked just like magic..

Comment: My grandkids are going to be telling stories about that time grandpappy Sammitch got a StackOverflow answer about curl accepted over the guy that actually wrote the thing.

Comment: I suppose that I should mention that there is a caveat to this approach in that because curl is streaming the request body from file it may not necessarily know the actual length of the request, and therefore may not necessarily set a `Content-Length:` header. This means that the remote side will consider the transfer complete when the connection closes, regardless of if the transfer is complete or not. If this poses an unacceptable risk, then you'll need that pile of RAM after all.

Comment: What annoys me is that this answer makes *a different* POST than what was asked about. Apparently the question was wrong?

Comment: Daniel, I apologize if there was confusion with the ask but that's what we are currently using to post i.e. 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode. I was not sure about changing content-type and was under impression that POST will not work if I change/remove it from curl command. @LMC solution works fine too but I've only tested with first 100 records from file and when I tried to run his script to encode whole file it's taking too longer to finish encoding. I've waited for around 30 - 35 mins and it haven't finished so I had to cancel.

Comment: @Sammitch Yes, you are correct. I am seeing issues as you mentioned even though we have enough RAM on machine. Is there any way to get over this issue?

Comment: @sandy did you try the first option in my answer? Does not uses `sed` to insert encoded new lines and writes to file directly, no vars. Should perform better than the other.

Comment: @LMC Yes, I am using 1st script but I had to make some updates to it like in the first command you are using quote where it should be unquote and also updated truncate with sed since when I've tried with small amount of data curl POST returned error so I had to update script to use sed but seems like I should use truncate -d instead of sed and just change it from qoute to unquote at the top. I've made above changes and ran the script and it's still running(from past 20 mins).

Comment: @sandy it must be `quote` because it url encodes. Can you try with an small csv the whole process? Even if the server does not accept it it could help to know if encoding is correct.

Comment: @LMC Okay, it gives me error 500. one thing I noticed is we should be using tr -d '\r' since we are executing curl in linux. I've tried both with \r and \n but no luck.

Comment: Is that a windows, a Mac or a Linux file? Also, there's a big performance mistake on my script which I'm trying to fix: it opens a python context for each line!

Comment: @LMC Yes, It's Linux file but I just changed your script to have \r instead of \n and replaced quote to unqoute for input params(list_id, form_id and file_name) and it just worked fine.

Comment: @LMC I think it's running for too long because we are calling python for each line read from the file, may be we should simplify this script to be written in python itself.

Comment: @sandy changed 1st option to one with much better performance. Could you try it please?

Comment: @LMC Wow, you are amazing!! that worked just fine and script finished like within seconds. Thank you for all your help on this and I can't thank you enough for what you did. you are absolute gem.... I marked your answer as accepted solution. Thanks again!!

Comment: @sandy thanks for helping make a better answer too.